# C linked list can't add Element at beginning

Tags: c, pointers

I'm fairly new to C and we got an excersie where we need to programm a linked list with predetermined functions and parameters. 
Now I  got a problem to add an new elemnt to the beginning of the list, everything else works, here the syntax.

```
int main(){

    Vector3D foo;
    foo.x = 521;
    foo.y = 2;
    foo.z = 3;

    VectorList * head;
    head = create_VL(NULL, &foo);

    insertElementBack(head, &foo);
    foo.x = 456;
    insertElementBack(head, &foo);
    foo.x = 2;
    insertElementFront(head, &foo);
    print_list(head);
    printf("%d\n", size(head));

}

void insertElementFront(VectorList* l, Vector3D* v){

    VectorList *previous, *new_VL;

    previous = &l;

    new_VL = NULL;
    new_VL = malloc(sizeof(VectorList));

    new_VL -> value = *v;

    new_VL -> next = previous;

    l = new_VL;
}

VectorList *create_VL(VectorList* l, Vector3D* v) {

    VectorList* new_VL = (VectorList*)malloc(sizeof(VectorList));

    if(new_VL == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error creating a new node.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    new_VL->value = *v;
    new_VL->next = l;

    return new_VL;
}

void insertElementBack(VectorList* l, Vector3D* v){

    VectorList *vl = l;

    while( vl -> next != NULL){
        vl = vl -> next;
    }

    VectorList *new_List = create_VL(NULL, v);
    vl -> next  = new_List;

}
```

The name and the parameters aren't allowed to be changed, I could solve this problem with a double pointer as parameter but it's not allowed. 
Could someone please give me a hint, I tried a lot of things but nothing worked.

Best

Martin

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. [Edit] your post to include the definition of VectorList.  By "it's not allowed", are you implying that your instructor has imposed limitations on your implementation? What do you mean by "nothing working"? Show us some input/output examples.

Comment: *"The name and the parameters aren't allowed to be changed"*, then change the **type** for `insertElementFront` to `VectorList*` and return a pointer to the new head pointer and assign it to `head` back in the caller, e.g. `head = insertElementFront(VectorList* l, Vector3D* v){ ... }`. That is your only alternative to passing a double pointer or using a global `head` (not recommended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `void insertElementFront(VectorList* l, Vector3D* v){` 
l is a local variable just holding the address of head. Changing the address locally does not affect head variable.

You can make head a global variable and approach the following way

```
void insertElementFront(VectorList* l, Vector3D* v){

    VectorList *new_VL;

    new_VL = NULL;
    new_VL = malloc(sizeof(VectorList));

    new_VL -> value = *v;

    new_VL -> next = l;

    head = new_VL
}
```

or You can return the head pointer

```
VectorList* insertElementFront(VectorList* l, Vector3D* v){

    VectorList *new_VL;

    new_VL = NULL;
    new_VL = malloc(sizeof(VectorList));

    new_VL -> value = *v;

    new_VL -> next = l;

    return new_VL
}
```

and

```
head = insertElementBack(head, &foo);
```

For more info look
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-write-functions-that-modify-the-head-pointer-of-a-linked-list/

Comment: We are also not allowed to change the return of the function, it was given this way. As all answers were things I tried or I'm not allowed to do, it means I need to add a global variable but for me it's ugly programming but if it's the only way to solve this, I need to do this way.

Answer (score 0):

You really should have included the definition of `VectorList` instead of making us guess at its structure, but your problem is probably this:

```
previous = &l;
```

`l` is a pointer to a `VectorList`. By doing `&l` you're taking the address of the pointer, not the `VectorList`. So when you do this

```
new_VL -> next = previous;
```

your `next` pointer now points to that pointer, not the `VectorList`. In fact, aren't you getting a warning on that? Don't ignore warnings.

Your second and bigger problem is `head` doesn't get updated to reflect the new head, and without being able to use double pointers your only way of solving that is to return the new head node as a return value from `insertElementFront`.